# Unable to boot into windows from GRUB menu (disk 'hd1,gpt1' not found)

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot

I dual booted Windows and Fedora KDE spin. When starting the system, if I select Windows Boot Manager, the following error prints

```
error: ../../grub-core/commands/search.c:315:no such device: 7E79-F46D.
error: ../../grub-core/net/net.c:1552:disk 'hd1,gpt1' not found.

Press any key to continue...
```

If I directly boot into Fedora, it works for Fedora but if I go to Windows Boot Manager first, then press any key as mentioned and then go to fedora, the following pops

```
error: ../../grub-core/net/net.c:1552:disk 'hd1,gpt1' not found.
error: ../../grub-core/loader/i386/efi/linux.c:258:you need to load the kernel first

Press any key to continue...
```

I have tried with different distributions(mint, manjaro, pop os) and the problem persists. I'm able to boot into windows from BIOS boot menu though. After reading online I tried to use ubuntu boot repair and it gave following output:

```
boot-repair-4ppa203                                              [20230314_0920]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Boot file info:      Grub2 (v2.00) in the file 
                       /Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-37-1.7.iso looks at sector 0 
                       of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can 
                       not be found at this location. Grub2 (v2.00) in the 
                       file /linuxmint-21.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso looks at 
                       sector 0 of the same hard drive for core.img, but 
                       core.img can not be found at this location.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbia32.efi /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/gcdia32.efi /efi/fedora/gcdx64.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/grubia32.efi /efi/fedora/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/mmia32.efi /efi/fedora/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/shim.efi /efi/fedora/shimia32.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/shimx64.efi /efi/fedora/grub.cfg

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub2/grub.cfg

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       btrfs
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 10 or 11 on sdb3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: UHD Graphics 620 from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604, bionic, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: Q80 Ver. 01.23.00 from HP
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0008,0000,0006,0007,0005,0004,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,e748a39c-9f78-44ed-8915-3765c578105b,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...o....................ISPH
Boot0002* Intel Corporation: IBA CL Slot 00FE v0112 BBS(Network,Intel Corporation: IBA CL Slot 00FE v0112,0x0)/PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)......ISPH
Boot0004* ST1000LM049-2GH172    BBS(HD,ST1000LM049-2GH172 ,0x400)/PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)......ISPH
Boot0005* LITEON CV8-8E128-HP   BBS(HD,LITEON CV8-8E128-HP ,0x400)/PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(2,0,0)......ISPH
Boot0006* SanDisk Cruzer Force 03002509050721090403 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0007  USB:      BBS(65535,,0x0)/PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)......ISPH
Boot0008* Fedora    HD(3,GPT,ad025592-09c4-4d88-9663-fadfa21250a2,0x67ebc800,0x12c000)/File(\EFI\fedora\shimx64.efi)....ISPH

b023680fdcebf4a4b32618450f63fdd3   sda3/BOOT/fbia32.efi
9d035bba35672038e084af85e1b8d1df   sda3/BOOT/fbx64.efi
33f35e43edabf2d5b94db33a2f8d2599   sda3/fedora/gcdia32.efi
a13472d919f98153986eed4d471285dc   sda3/fedora/gcdx64.efi
7e4b520bf3912dcbf972c73dbb5fe531   sda3/fedora/grubia32.efi
8f52418dc2e07dded3570ae1a60f17cb   sda3/fedora/grubx64.efi
7010d05a34cbf0c3e696df6a62f56015   sda3/fedora/mmia32.efi
bd6eccfe55c5ec7e206500ac01cb0cd4   sda3/fedora/mmx64.efi
88a7b0e2436865122255f78aa52edaec   sda3/fedora/shim.efi
b6410a7309a1aa9a05df02ea1954c02d   sda3/fedora/shimia32.efi
88a7b0e2436865122255f78aa52edaec   sda3/fedora/shimx64.efi
b6410a7309a1aa9a05df02ea1954c02d   sda3/BOOT/BOOTIA32.efi
88a7b0e2436865122255f78aa52edaec   sda3/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi
20ac8dde00311476f3755604eb0e545a   sdb1/Boot/bootx64.efi
20ac8dde00311476f3755604eb0e545a   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
27d382c5fc21df6f4a75baed05aa1d9d   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb3    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda4    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0363D3C5-E037-4DE4-B2AB-A524F4314F82
           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1          34      32767      32734    16M Microsoft reserved
sda2       32768 1743505407 1743472640 831.4G Microsoft basic data
sda3  1743505408 1744734207    1228800   600M EFI System
sda4  1744734208 1746831359    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
sda5  1746831360 1953523711  206692352  98.6G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk identifier: A48EA26A-2462-4A03-8D2A-0F74F610DCC4
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdb1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
sdb2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sdb3     239616 248980558 248740943 118.6G Microsoft basic data
sdb4  248981504 250066943   1085440   530M Windows recovery environment
Disk sdc: 14.3 GiB, 15376318464 bytes, 30031872 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x2c534026
      Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sdc1  *        0 1802239 1802240  880M  0 Empty
sdc2         964    5891    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
Disk zram0: 991.2 MiB, 1039298560 bytes, 253735 sectors
Disk zram1: 991.2 MiB, 1039298560 bytes, 253735 sectors
Disk zram2: 991.2 MiB, 1039298560 bytes, 253735 sectors
Disk zram3: 991.2 MiB, 1039298560 bytes, 253735 sectors
Disk zram4: 991.2 MiB, 1039298560 bytes, 253735 sectors
Disk zram5: 991.2 MiB, 1039298560 bytes, 253735 sectors
Disk zram6: 991.2 MiB, 1039298560 bytes, 253735 sectors
Disk zram7: 991.2 MiB, 1039298560 bytes, 253735 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST1000LM049-2GH1:;
1:17.4kB:16.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:16.8MB:893GB:893GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
3:893GB:893GB:629MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
4:893GB:894GB:1074MB:ext4::;
5:894GB:1000GB:106GB:btrfs::;
sdb:128GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA LITEON CV8-8E128:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:127GB:127GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:127GB:128GB:556MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
sdc:15.4GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:SanDisk Cruzer Force:;
2:494kB:3017kB:2523kB:::esp;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sdc: 2.88MiB:14664MiB:14661MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                              
├─sda1                                               237662f0-b87f-42ce-8681-38220d97b59e                        Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda2 ntfs     227C126A7C1238CD                     a2ee1834-5c53-4c4d-ba12-aa5fac04b96e New Volume             Basic data partition
├─sda3 vfat     BE67-4BD6                            ad025592-09c4-4d88-9663-fadfa21250a2                        EFI System Partition
├─sda4 ext4     32bdddcb-ffdb-4824-881b-e28f0d03ace5 69b1c64a-957e-49d6-b375-ade22b66da81                        
└─sda5 btrfs    b67bb84c-2381-4cbe-8ccd-ea1ed8c9f5c4 7adda1d6-0bc4-4b51-bcc0-6c0b7cffbda5 fedora_localhost-live  
sdb                                                                                                              
├─sdb1 vfat     9228-4C98                            e748a39c-9f78-44ed-8915-3765c578105b                        EFI system partition
├─sdb2                                               ab205258-94e6-40d6-a308-8cf225b8a037                        Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdb3 ntfs     8E5E38FF5E38E19F                     e6dcbd4d-96c9-4c0b-9826-ac7aecfc37a8                        Basic data partition
└─sdb4 ntfs     EE1EAD5E1EAD2117                     8003e7fa-b647-47ae-9e9f-7bce2481a4d7                        
sdc    iso9660  2020-06-13-00-42-55-00                                                    Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sdc1 iso9660  2020-06-13-00-42-55-00               2c534026-01                          Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
└─sdc2 vfat     D055-8513                            2c534026-02                          Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

             Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2   771.3G   7% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3   581.4M   3% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda4   735.7M  18% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sda5    90.8G   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sdb1    69.4M  28% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb3    61.9G  48% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb3
/dev/sdb4    88.5M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4
/dev/sdc         0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


===================== sda3/efi/fedora/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=dev 32bdddcb-ffdb-4824-881b-e28f0d03ace5
set prefix=($dev)/grub2
export $prefix
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

======================== sda4/grub2/grub.cfg (filtered) ========================

Windows Boot Manager (on sdb1)   osprober-efi-9228-4C98
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sda4: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 832.206066132 = 893.574459392  grub2/grub.cfg                                 1
 832.257247925 = 893.629415424  vmlinuz-0-rescue-e4ac8fd2f5fb4a1c806fa70a643abcb1  2
 832.282222748 = 893.656231936  vmlinuz-6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64                  2
 832.407222748 = 893.790449664  initramfs-0-rescue-e4ac8fd2f5fb4a1c806fa70a643abcb1.img  4
 832.442329407 = 893.828145152  initramfs-6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64.img            1

====================== sdc/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =======================

Boot-Repair-Disk session
Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)

==================== sdc: Location of files loaded by Grub =====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================


/dev/sdb1: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sdb2: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000000

/dev/sdb4: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000001
Unknown BootLoader on sdc


BTRFS detected on sda5
ls sda5:

---
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/boot-sav/sda5/ 
MOUNTCODE=0
---
os-prober before @ subvol mount:
/dev/sdb1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
---


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix
```

I have installed Windows on SSD and Fedora on HDD by giving it 100gb of space.

Fast boot is disabled.

The boot menu works perfectly fine with ubuntu as it manages bootloader installation itself (atleast I think so).

Comment: @Peregrino69 I'm really new to this...thanks for pointing out. I have added it as an edit. I did find some solutions by googling but I dont really understand much of it as in most solutions steps to achieve it is not mentioned.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I got the gist...thanks...made the edits now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the ESP partition on your `sdb1` disk was probably reformatted at some point after installing Fedora, and Fedora's GRUB configuration file has not been updated since then. The ESP's volume serial number (i.e. the thing used on FAT32 partitions in place of a filesystem UUID) has changed, and GRUB is still looking for the old serial number.

If your Fedora has the `os-prober` package installed, the fix might be as simple as booting into Fedora and running this command as root:

```
grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

That should cause `os-prober` to re-detect the location of the Windows Boot Manager and replace the old FAT32 filesystem serial number 7E79-F46D with the new one, which would seem to be 9228-4C98.

Alternatively, you could edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` manually in Fedora and replace the string `7E79-F46D` with `9228-4C98`.

The message `disk 'hd1,gpt1' not found` could be a result of the fact that the `os-prober` adds multiple "search hints" for each OS it finds. But because it cannot definitively know the firmware's disk detection order, it has just guessed that the partition `sdb1` might be `hd1,gpt1` for the firmware and thus for GRUB.

The firmware might actually detect the drives in a different order, making the `os-prober`'s guess wrong. But as long as the filesystem UUIDs/FAT32 serial numbers are correct, those will have higher precedence for GRUB: as long as GRUB can find the filesystem with the right UUID/serial number, it won't care about what the firmware will call it. Since the serial number seems to have been changed, GRUB won't find the old serial number it's looking for, and will fall back to the guessed `hd1,gpt1` identifier, which is apparently also not correct.